# What is that "Oh yeah!" gesture that anime characters do called?

Tags: culture

Often in anime, I've noticed a gesture is done when a character remembers a previous event of theirs, or something comes to mind. One hand is made into a fist, of which the bottom of it will fall flat onto their palm of the other hand, sometimes followed by a quip or phrase such as "Hold on!" or "That's it!" indicating they have realized new means.

I'm not sure else how to refer to the hand gesture, and that's my question. What is this hand gesture called? I had tried looking up some gif images of it for reference to add to a group joke, but had no luck with getting the right name for it or finding anything relevant.

Comment: This seems more like a Japanese culture question than an anime question. It seems like the gesture (if not the meaning) that you're referring to is on page 19: https://www.scribd.com/doc/46165206/70-Japanese-Gestures. The trope is referred to here: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PalmFistTap

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It called 合点 (Gatten). [Google image search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E5%90%88%E7%82%B9%20%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A7%E3%82%B9%E3%83%81%E3%83%A3%E3%83%BC&tbm=isch)

It's pretty common gesture in Japan (and other countries)
I do it in real life too.

Also there is TV show called "[gatten](http://www9.nhk.or.jp/gatten/)" that describe something and guest did gatten it.

Do you gatten to this answer?

Comment: I did in fact gatten